# Web Api Get Overload Throws Multiple actions were found that match the request

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, routes, overloading, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an api controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
[Authorize]
public class UsersController : ApiController
```

that has two Get methods:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(ODataQueryOptions<ApplicationUser> options)
{
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new List<ApplicationUser>());
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
{
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new List<ApplicationUser>());
}
```

Calling http://mysite/api/users?$filter=FirstName eq 'George' 
or
Calling http://mysite/api/users

causes the exception Multiple actions were found that match the request.

Commenting out either method will cause the other to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All the Web API routing is about converting `url` into `controller/action`. And its mapping must be unambiguous.

In case that we would have only the first action`Get(ODataQueryOptions<ApplicationUser> options)` it would match both urls below:

```
http://mysite/api/users?$filter=FirstName+eq+'George' 
http://mysite/api/users
```

The first url will be converted into call `Get(someODataValue)`, the second could be `Get(null)`

The same could be applied to second method `Get()` without params, because both urls will be converted into parameterless call `Get()` *(OData part will be skipped)*

So the solution usually should be in two methods, which are really unique by params. E.g. one is object/refence the second is valueType/int

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(ODataQueryOptions<ApplicationUser> options)
{ ... }

[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(int id)
{ ... }
```

Comment: So what if I want a get all with no parameters? Just don't pass the options? If so will that satisfy the REST gurus?

Comment: No param... means give me list of all (well, something like that;). Param INT Id means GET one item with provided key... Param as OData ... means give me list but with these restricitons ($filter,$orderby...) REST gurus will love it, because that's the way it is designed ;) Please, check the table provided here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Example